# how to retrieve insensitive distinct elements in oracle data table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have  a table with a couple of thousand records. When I run a statement like

```
select distinct issue_type from data_tab;
```

the result is:

```
issue_type
C
c
```

What could be the efficient way to get a case insensitive result set, so the result is:

```
issue_type
C
```

I can use sql like

```
select issue_type from data_tab
where data_id in 
( select min(data_id) from data_tab
group by upper(issue_type));
```

which is ~7 times slower than a simple distinct statement. I would like to know if there is a better way. Any suggestions in JPQL or (native oracle) SQL should be of great help.

Thanks in advance, Vardhan.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of nesting SQL, why not just write

```
select distinct upper(issue_type) from data_tab;
```

It should only be marginally slower than the original query, if you don't already have an index on `issue_type`. Otherwise, you can make a function-based index on `upper(issue_type)`, but that would probably be a bit extreme for your use-case.

Comment: Thanks Lucas. I looked like a hardcore idiot in writing that nested statement. :-) nice day.

Comment: This is the sort of query which we should only be running as part of ad hoc investigation, so it hardly merits an index.

Comment: Well, sometimes you don't see the forest for the trees ;-)